# Class not found even exist on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, class

I have a custom module and i tried to extend this class in my **Image.php** file: **Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image**

```
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Element;

class Image extends Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image
{ 
    /**
     * Get image preview url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getUrl()
    {
        return $this->getValue();
    }
}
```

When i run the compile command i receive this err: 
14% 1 sec 52.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Class 'vendor\namespace\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Element\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image' not found in app/code/vendorm/namespace/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Element/Image.php on line 9.

Even this class exist at this path, i still receive this error.

Does anyone know why this happen?

Comment: try to extend with \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image
```

Without the \ Magento is looking within the module for the class.

Comment: No worries man!